# Firebase Crash report

Tags: ios, core-data, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

my app crashed, and while i was relying on firebase crash report to get some answers; the stack trace just didn't make any sense to me.

this is what I was able to get from them, how can I make use of those numbers they offer me:

[image]

Comment: This crash report is not symbolicated. Did you upload your apps symbols? Check their documentation on how to do that.

Comment: See the documentation on how to upload your symbol files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files